# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException : Problems with String.substring() and String.indexOf()

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a program that reverses the word order in a sentence. (e.g. "the red hat belongs to John" => "John to belongs hat red the") I walked myself through the do-while loop, but I don't understand why there is an Index Exception.

Thanks for your help,

JonBrown

---

Exception :

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -23
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at WordReverse.main(WordReverse.java:17)
```

Code :

```
   public class WordReverse 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            String input = "The red had belongs to John";
            String reverse = "";
            int lastSpace = 0;

            do
            {
            //Isolate Word w/ Preceding Space
            int startIndex = lastSpace;
            int endIndex = input.indexOf(' ', startIndex + 1);

            //Add Word to front of String 
            reverse = input.substring(startIndex, endIndex) + reverse;

            //Add Preceding Space for First Iteration
            if (lastSpace == 0) reverse = " " + reverse;

            //Reset Last Space
            lastSpace = endIndex;

            // Repeat Loop Until line14 .indexOf returns -1 due to lack of " ". 
            }while (lastSpace != -1);

            System.out.println(reverse);
        }
    }
```

Comment: issue is with  input.indexOf(' ', startIndex + 1);  returns -1 for last word of the input String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, your problem is with `lastIndex` being -1 .  This fix breaks out of the loop when that happens, but not before copying the remainder of the string to the result:

```
public class WordReverse 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = "The red hat belongs to John";
        String reverse = "";
        int lastSpace = 0;

        do
        {
            //Isolate Word w/ Preceding Space
            int startIndex = lastSpace;
            int endIndex = input.indexOf(' ', startIndex+1);
            if (endIndex==-1) {
                reverse = input.substring(startIndex) + reverse;
                break;
            }

            //Add Word to front of String 
            reverse = input.substring(startIndex, endIndex) + reverse;

            //Add Preceding Space for First Iteration
            if (lastSpace == 0) reverse = " " + reverse;

            //Reset Last Space
            lastSpace = endIndex;

            // Repeat Loop Until line14 .indexOf returns -1 due to lack of " ". 
        }while (true);

        System.out.println(reverse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN
[String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public string Substring(
    int startIndex,
    int length
)
```

It should be something like this:

```
reverse += input.substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a split for convenience

```
    String input = "The red had belongs to John";

    String arr[] = input.split(" ");

    for (int x = arr.length -1; x >= 0; x--) 
         System.out.println(arr[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is more elegant:

```
public class WordReverse 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = "The red had belongs to John";
        String array = input.split(" ");
        for( int i = array.length()-1; i >= 0; i++ )
          System.out.print( array[ i ] + " " );
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow input.split() is powerful, and I'm glad I never have to do it the old fashioned way again.

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the last space (right before "John"), `endIndex` value is -1. Then you try to call `subString()` with an `endIndex` smaller than `startIndex`, which causes the crash.